# How to search strings with an alternate character?

Tags: mysql

I have a field where I save strings, like:

```
"one two-tree"
"one-two-tree"
"one-two tree"
"one two tree"
```

When I do a SELECT, I want to retrieve strings that have either "-" or " " (space). Example:

When I do:

```
Select name from table where name="one two tree"
```

I want it to bring also results where there is either space or -, in this case returning all string exemplified above.

Is there a wildcard for this?

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use `replace`:

```
select name
from yourtable
where replace(name, '-', ' ') = 'one two tree'
```

Answer (score 1):

There is, but it is slow: you can use `REGEXP`:

```
SELECT name
FROM table
WHERE name REGEXP 'one[- ]two[- ]tree'
```

or you can use replacements:

```
SELECT name
FROM table
WHERE REPLACE(name, '-', ' ') = 'one two three'
```

but your best bet is to make an additional column where you will have a normalised `name` (with dashes always replaced with spaces, for example) so you can take advantage of indices.

Comment: What if I want to retrieve when space or - is absent?

For example: 'onetwo three'

Comment: Then you can put `[- ]?` into regexp. Or replace spaces and also dashes with empty string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `LIKE` condition with '%' (wildcard operator) for this.

e.g.

```
SELECT name from table_name WHERE name LIKE '%-%' OR name LIKE '% %'
-- will return all names that have `-` or ` `.
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as standard SQL, you must use "or", or "like". depending on what exactly you want. EXAMPLE: Select name from table where name like "one?two?tree".

However, mySQL supports a REGEX extension that will give you what you want:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/pattern-matching.html